# Multiple Counts, trying to keep them separate, but they multiply together

Tags: mysql

I have four counts in the one query, and all the counts are counting different fields of the same table.  When I run them, it diplays the count of each on above 0, multiplied together, in all cells that have a count above 0.

I have researched ways to stop the counts from crossing.

DISTINCT:
I have tried distinct, which then just gives me a 1 if there is a number above 0, and 0 when there isn't.

Sub queries:
I tried this and have a code issue for using the same table, even with different aliases.

Original query:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(lastname,', ', firstname), 
  A.gender, 
  DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%d %b %y'), 
  DATE_FORMAT(dod, '%d %b %y'), 
  CASE WHEN NOT dod = '0000-00-00' then TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,dob,dod) else 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,dob,Curdate()) end, 
  B.Name, 
  COUNT(M.REF),
  COUNT(M1.AR1),
  COUNT(M2.AR2),
  COUNT(M3.TMO),
  refID 
FROM 
  refs A 
LEFT JOIN 
  teams B 
ON 
  A.Nationality=B.TeamID 
LEFT JOIN 
  matches M 
ON 
  A.refID=M.REF 
LEFT JOIN 
  matches M1 
ON 
  A.refID=M1.AR1
LEFT JOIN 
  matches M2 
ON 
  A.refID=M2.AR2 
LEFT JOIN 
  matches M3 
ON 
  A.refID=M3.TMO
GROUP BY 
  refID
ORDER BY 
  lastname
```

The issue area is this:

```
COUNT(M.REF),
COUNT(M1.AR1),
COUNT(M2.AR2),
COUNT(M3.TMO),
```

I have tried this and just get 1 or 0:

```
COUNT(distinct M.REF) as refCount,
COUNT(distinct M1.AR1) as AR1Count,
COUNT(distinct M2.AR2) as AR2Count,
COUNT(distinct M3.TMO) as TMOCount,
```

I tried this and get an error of "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'M ON A.refID = M.REF LEFT JOIN (SELECT M1.AR1, COUNT(*) as AR1Count from ma' at line 16":

```
  refCount,
  AR1Count,
  AR2Count,
  TMOCount,
  refID 
FROM 
  refs A 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT M.REF, COUNT(*) as refCount from matches M GROUP BY REF) matches M ON A.refID = M.REF 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT M1.AR1, COUNT(*) as AR1Count from matches M1 GROUP BY AR1) matches M1 ON A.refID = M1.AR1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT M2.AR2, COUNT(*) as AR2Count from matches M2 GROUP BY AR2) matches M2 ON A.refID = M2.AR2 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT M3.TMO, COUNT(*) as TMOCount from matches M3 GROUP BY TMO) matches M3 ON A.refID = M3.TMO
```

Can someone please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use `CASE ` and `SUM`  in order to run different counts on the same query? Can you tell us what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: in general cases that is **not** how  you should write a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) query .. *"SQL-92 and earlier does **not** permit queries for which the **select list**, HAVING condition, or **ORDER BY list** refer to **nonaggregated columns** that are **not named in the GROUP BY clause**"* which you are doing here without table structures we can't know if MySQL was able to use [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct data.

Comment: @Elanochecer
I have a DB that records information of rugby games.
This query should tell me all the match officials, and how many games they have refereed, assistant refereed and been TMO.

The info is taken from the matches table where it is supposed to count how many times each person has filled that role.

However, it doesn't.

RaymondNijland
Do you mean the GROUP BY in the sub queries?  if so, I searched SO and found that was a solution for someone, but they were using different tables so it clearly didn't work for me.  I'll have a look at that reference for inspiration.

Comment: Any other thoughts on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it.  You need to use sub queries for the additional counts, and you don't then need the additional joins.  This took me days to find, so hopefully this may help someone else.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(lastname,', ', firstname), 
  A.gender, 
  DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%d %b %y'), 
  DATE_FORMAT(dod, '%d %b %y'), 
  CASE WHEN NOT dod = '0000-00-00' then TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,dob,dod) else 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,dob,Curdate()) end, 
  B.Name, 
  COUNT(M.REF) AS refCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(M.AR1) from matches M WHERE M.AR1=A.refID) AS AR1Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(M.AR2) from matches M WHERE M.AR2=A.refID) AS AR2Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(M.TMO) from matches M WHERE M.TMO=A.refID) AS TMOCount,
  refID 
FROM 
  refs A 
LEFT JOIN 
  teams B 
ON 
  A.Nationality=B.TeamID 
INNER JOIN 
  matches M 
ON
  A.refID=M.REF
GROUP BY 
  refID
ORDER BY 
  lastname;
```